# VBA - Vlookup returns on development but not when added to ribbon

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I've a strange problem.

the following code will run using F8 or pressing the run button on the development module.

**But** when added to the excel ribbon as a macro by the following process the vlookup will return #N/A  :

1.right click on the excel toolbar > customize the ribbon

2. choose macro commands
3. add it to a new group.

the code is :

```
 Sub Compare()

'set primary Workbook
'find last cell'
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Dim LastCellRowNumber As Long
    Set WS = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With WS
        Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
        LastCellRowNumber = LastCell.Row
        'MsgBox (LastCell.Row)
    End With

'Adding Index Column
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
[A2].Formula = "=G2&H2"
Range("A2:A" & LastCellRowNumber).FillDown

'adding headers
[Ag1].Value = "Resale"
[Ah1].Value = "Cost"
[Ai1].Value = "disti"

'set primary Workbook
 Dim Pri As Workbook
 Set Pri = ActiveWorkbook

 'open company quotes
  Workbooks.Open ("R:\company\DATA\company quotes.xlsx")
 'find last cell'
    Dim WSq As Worksheet
    Dim LastCellq As Range
    Dim LastCellRowNumberq As Long
    Set WSq = Worksheets("Quote Summary")
        With WSq
        Set LastCellq = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
        LastCellRowNumberq = LastCellq.Row
        'MsgBox (LastCell.Row)
    End With

Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Dim quotes As Workbook
Set quotes = ActiveWorkbook
[A2].Formula = "=J2&B2"
Range("A2:A" & LastCellRowNumberq).FillDown

Pri.Activate
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To LastCellRowNumber

Dim result As String
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Range("AG" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("A" & i), Workbooks("company quotes.xlsx").Worksheets("Quote Summary").Range("A2:AS" & LastCellRowNumberq), 17, False)
Range("AH" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("A" & i), Workbooks("company quotes.xlsx").Worksheets("Quote Summary").Range("A2:AS" & LastCellRowNumberq), 19, False)
Range("Ai" & i) = Application.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("A" & i), Workbooks("company quotes.xlsx").Worksheets("Quote Summary").Range("A2:AS" & LastCellRowNumberq), 20, False)


Next i


 End Sub
```

Comment: It might not be the source of your problem but you have some referencing issues as you're not specifying the `Workbook` or `Worksheet` for a lot of your references. Also, you should avoid using `Select`, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros for some more info

Comment: I wasn't using select, but i do think its a referencing issue, maybe when i put the vba in the ribbon , it has a different referencing .  but i don't understand well enough how to overcome this referencing issue .  what should i do to set the reference ?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to fix any referencing issues I could find but you'll need to have a look through and make sure all of the `Range` references are prefixed with the correct `Workbook` and `Worksheet` as it wasn't too clear which worksheet they were coming from in the original code:

```
Sub Compare()

'Set primary Workbook
'Find last cell
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LastCellRowNumber As Long
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
LastCellRowNumber = WS.Cells(WS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'MsgBox (LastCell.Row)

'Adding Index Column
WS.Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
WS.Range("A2:A" & LastCellRowNumber).Formula = "=G2&H2"

'adding headers
WS.Range("AG1").Value = "Resale"
WS.Range("AH1").Value = "Cost"
WS.Range("AI1").Value = "disti"

'open company quotes
Dim wbCompQuotes As Workbook
Set wbCompQuotes = Workbooks.Open ("R:\company\DATA\company quotes.xlsx")

'find last cell'
Dim wsQuoteSum As Worksheet
Dim LastCellRowNumberq As Long
Set wsQuoteSum = wbCompQuotes.Worksheets("Quote Summary")
LastCellRowNumberq = wsQuoteSum.Cells(wsQuoteSum.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'MsgBox (LastCell.Row)

wsQuoteSum.Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
wsQuoteSum.Range("A2:A" & LastCellRowNumberq).Formula = "=J2&B2"

Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To LastCellRowNumber
    WS.Range("AG" & i) = Application.VLookup(WS.Range("A" & i), wsQuoteSum.Range("A2:AS" & LastCellRowNumberq), 17, False)
    WS.Range("AH" & i) = Application.VLookup(WS.Range("A" & i), wsQuoteSum.Range("A2:AS" & LastCellRowNumberq), 19, False)
    WS.Range("AI" & i) = Application.VLookup(WS.Range("A" & i), wsQuoteSum.Range("A2:AS" & LastCellRowNumberq), 20, False)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: still doesn't work when i use it as a ribbon button . :\